# Is deep copy necessary on passing an ArrayList to a copy constructor?

Tags: java, design-patterns, arraylist, constructor, cloning

I'm trying to figure out the best way to implement the code I'm working on.

I have two options of how to pass the data to my constructor.

**First way**

```
private String ISBN;
private String title;
private ArrayList <Person>authors = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList <BookCategory>subjectCategories = new ArrayList<>();


public Book (String isbn, String title,
        ArrayList <Person>authors, ArrayList <BookCategory>categories) {

    //call the checkISBN method
    boolean check = checkISBN(isbn);
    if (check ==true) {
        this.ISBN= isbn;
    }
    else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid ISBN");
    }
    this.title = title;
    for(int index =0; index<authors.size(); index++) {
        this.authors.add(authors.get(index));
    }
}
```

**Second way**

```
private String ISBN;
private String title;
private ArrayList <Person>authors = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList <BookCategory>subjectCategories = new ArrayList<>();


public Book (String isbn, String title,
        ArrayList <Person>authors, ArrayList <BookCategory>categories) {

    //call the checkISBN method
    boolean check = checkISBN(isbn);
    if (check ==true) {
        this.ISBN= isbn;
    }
    else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid ISBN");
    }
    this.title = title;
    this.authors = authors;
}
```

Does it make a difference?

I'm not sure because it seems like it would be unnecessary to declare the `Book` with a copy of the Authors `ArrayList` instead of the original `ArrayList`.

What is the correct way to do this, and why?

Comment: Neither is a deep copy, one is just using the same instance, the other is doing a shallow copy.

Comment: So really i would do:  this.authors.add(new Person(authors.get(index)))?(All authors are Persons)

Comment: A safe way is to serialize the `Person` objects, then deserialize. This ensures everything is a brand new reference.

Comment: @Yahya I'm not sure i know what you're talking about, could you clarify?

Comment: Do you still need time to upvote and accept the best answer below?!

Answer (score 0):

If you copy, you spend some time to gain security. If you didn't copy, then a client could construct a `Book` with some authors and later change the authors which will be reflected in the `Book`:

```
List<Person> authors = new ArrayList<>();
authors.add(new Person("J.K. Rowling"));
Book harryPotter = new Book("some ISBN", "Harry Potter", authors, new ArrayList<>());
// Harry Potter is written by J.K. Rowling.

authors.set(1, new Person("pkpnd"));
// Harry Potter is now written by pkpnd??
```

If that sounds bad in your use case, you should make a copy.

Note that you aren't performing a *deep* copy, only a shallow copy. You'll need to create entirely new `Person` objects when copying:

```
this.authors = new ArrayList<>();
for (Person p : authors) {
    this.authors.add(new Person(p.getName()));
}
```

Comment: oooh makes sense yes that could be a problem. Not a huge one since we want this program to be user friendly and capable of correcting mistakes, but potentially an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how to make a deep copy of your class with `serialization`. This ensures everything is a brand new reference:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Person implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name;

    public Person(String name) {this.name = name;}

    public String setName(String name) {return this.name = name;}

    /**
     * make a deep copy with serialization without creating files
     * convert class object to a stream of bytes then restore it
     */
    public Person deepCopy() {  
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
            oos.writeObject(this);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
            bos.close();

            return (Person) new ObjectInputStream(
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray())).readObject();

        } catch (IOException  | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        Person p1 = new Person("Yahya");
        Person p2 = p1;
        Person p3 = p1.deepCopy();

        // change the original object and check if that affect the others
        p1.setName("Uknown");           
        System.out.println("P1: " + p1.name + " ... P2: " + p2.name 
                                            + " ... P3: " + p3.name);

    }
}
```

**Output**

```
P1: Uknown ... P2: Uknown ... P3: Yahya
```

Comment: Looks cool! A little out of my league at the moment but I'm sure I'll learn how to do it eventually :) What does it do exactly?

Comment: @user9832813 create a `deepCopy()` method from inside your class, you just need to invoke it upon each object of the class `Person` as I did it in the *Test*. `deepCopy()` converts the `Person` object to a Stream of Bytes then converts it back to an Object of type `Person`. In other words, a workaround to obtain a totally brand new instance reference of the class `Person` so any change in the original object will not affect the copied ones as it's shown in the *Test*. All you need is to add the `deepCopy` method to your `Person`.. if it helped you please accept my answer :)